# Spring integration http gateways with struts action mapping

Tags: spring-integration, struts

I am working on an application which is using struts and spring framework integration.

I would like to introduce spring integration http inbound and outbound gateways.

Can anyone please help me understanding how struts can be integrated with SI gateways?

Comment: Spring Integration integration with Struts2 doesn't exist. You can integrate Struts2 with Spring and separate http inbound and outbound gateways.

Comment: Thanks for the useful information. In my case using separate http inbound and outbound gateways would voilate existing design ( spring + struts2). I believe SI should provide some alternative to achieve http gateways which would take request from struts execute methods and return back to same execute methods so to forward it some front end ( jsp).

Comment: It violates existing design in any ways, because there's *no* integration exists for spring integration or if ever existed a plugin then should be already deprecated. Struts deprecated a lot of plugins, and many of them were using extensions to the framework to provide support for some features like Spring. If you can use SI with Spring then you should not have any problem with Struts2 because this design (spring+struts2) is never violated. There only might be problems with http calls that interfere with each other and these calls could be handled by SI separately.

Comment: Agreed. I have tried calling gateways inside struts execute methods In order to trigger SI Independently. Problem is retrieving flow back to execute method to continue further processing ( forwarding it some jsps based on sucess or failure of of gateway results ) . Have use some filters too and tried to redirect discard channels to gateways default reply channel. It doesn't work. Looking for tutorial which would achieve separate SI flow within struts execute method. Thanks for the reply Roman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Struts is servlet level technology, you should just call Spring Integration Gateway from that execute method and your Integration flow will be initiated: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.11.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#gateway.

Spring Integration HTTP is fully based on the Spring MVC. Don't see reason to introduce some complexity if we can just delegate from Struts.

Comment: Thanks for quick suggestions. I tried calling gateways within execute method of action classes. As you mentioned the integration flow got triggered. Problem is it how would we get the integration flow back to same execute methods? So we can forward it to some jsp. I have tried redirecting flow back to default reply channel of gateway from service activator ( by assigning service activator's output channel to gateways default reply channel ) but it does not came back. Having said that it only came when some exception was thrown. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, that sounds like you have to show your code so far.

Comment: I am trying to redirect output channel of discard channel to service activator and redirecting service activators reply channel (service activator method is returning void and my gateways method is expecting the return type as LIST) to gateways default reply channel. That's causing issue ( hung thread ). If I redirect discard channels reply channel to gateways reply channel it is working fine. I guess I shall return list from service activator and it will work fine. Thanks Artem

Comment: That's correct. The reply logic works correctly only if `replyChannel` is present in headers, even if you send to the `reply-channel` of the Gateway.